# Having trouble using push on object into my Topic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm working on a forum. Here is my Topic schema

```
const topicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: {
    type: String,
    ref: "User", // Reference to the user who made the Topic update
    required: true,
  },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  posts: { type: Array, ref: "Posts" }, // posts array
  postCount: { type: Number, default: 1, required: true },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Using this schema and a form that the user fills out, this code sets up to save the inputted data to the database.

```
const topic = new Topic({
      title: req.body.title,
      content: content,
      author: req.body.author,
    });
```

I have similar code for my message response. I have a Posts schema which saves a posts message and author.

```
router.post("/:topicId"

const { topicId } = req.params;

const topic = Topic.findById(topicId);

const post = new Post({
  author: req.body.author,
  message: message,
});
console.log(post);
console.log(topic.title);

topic.posts.push(post);

// Data from form is valid. Save statue update.
post
 .save()
 .then(function (post) {
   res.redirect("/");
   })
 .catch(function (err) {
   console.log(err);
   });
```

Everything about my code works perfectly fine. When I make a topic or make a post response inside either form, it works as intended and I'm getting zero errors.

My problem lies with using `push` inside my post code and this is the error I'm getting: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`. I want it so when a user creates a post inside a certain topic, the message content gets pushed to the `posts` field (*Topic schema*) of said topic, that way I can loop through all the posts to display the responses on the page. But every time I attempt to add the post to the topic, I'm getting the above undefined error.

Comment: It seems to me that when you're creating Topic its posts field is undefined. You can either give a default to posts in your schema or initiate an empty array for posts while creating the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mongoose query can be executed in one of two ways.

- First, if you pass in a callback function, Mongoose will execute the query asynchronously and pass the results to the callback.
- A query also has a .then() function, and thus can be used as a promise.

While calling `Topic.findById`, you are not treating it as an async call. Then, when you call `topic.posts.push(post)`, since posts is undefined you get the `"Cannot read properties of undefined"` error. You need to await the result of Model.findById call before you are pushing the new item to posts array. For example,

```
const { topicId } = req.params;

// Use async/await to fetch the topic from the database
const topic = await Topic.findById(topicId);
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixed the error I was getting but for some reason the value isn't being pushed to the `posts` field. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I forgot to use `topic.save()` after so my code has been fixed.